# Copy commit comments to windows clipboard

Tags: perl, svn, tortoisesvn, commit, clearcase

I recently saw a nifty hack for ClearCase where the version number was added to the Windows clipboard as part of a commit. The hack look like this:

```
@rem = ' PERL for Windows NT - ccperl must be in search path
@echo off
ccperl %0 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
goto endofperl
@rem ';

#$CLEARCASE_COMMENT = $ENV{CLEARCASE_COMMENT};
#$CLEARCASE_FILE1   = $ENV{CLEARCASE_PN};
#$CLEARCASE_FILE2   = $ENV{CLEARCASE_XPN};

#print "DEBUG: $CLEARCASE_FILE2\n";

#$message = "Element: $CLEARCASE_FILE2";

use Win32::Clipboard;
Win32::Clipboard::Set($ENV{CLEARCASE_XPN});
#$CLIP = Win32::Clipboard();
#$CLIP->Set($ENV{CLEARCASE_XPN});


__END__
:endofperl
```

Now, we have moved (or begun to move) from CC to Subversion and one of my users is rather keen on having the same functionality in Subversion (and I guess TortoiseSVN).

Anybody seen or tried anything like this in a svn environment?

Comment: Please note that the answer does not have to be limited to Perl. On the contrary; perl comes with ClearCase and since I want to leave CC I'd rather not have to install Perl alongside TortoiseSVN but just use TortoiseSVN alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a client side hook that only used standard Windows tools. The resulting bat file, "tortoisesvn-post-commit.bat", ended up like this

```
@echo off
rem TortoiseSVN Client Side post-commit hook script
rem script <Path> <Depth> <MessageFile> <Revision> <Error>
setlocal
set tsvnPath=%1
set tsvnDepth=%2
set tsvnMsgFile=%3
set tsvnRevision=%4
set tsvnError=%5
set tsvnCwd=%6

rem send the revision to the clipboard
echo %tsvnRevision% | clip
endlocal
```

It was then an easy task to set up a call from TortoiseSVN to use this. Go to settings, then "Hook Scripts", and add a hook with type "post-commit-hook" and point that to the script above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tortoise SVN does support [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

Looks like you'd create a `post-commit` hook to run `...\path\to\perl ...\path\to\script.pl`

post-commit hooks receive the following in `@ARGV`:

```
$ARGV[0]: PATH
$ARGV[1]: DEPTH
$ARGV[2]: MESSAGEFILE
$ARGV[3]: REVISION
$ARGV[4]: ERROR
$ARGV[5]: CWD
```

These are defined in the linked document.

So the script would be

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::Clipboard qw( );

my $clip = Win32::Clipboard();
$clip->Set($ARGV[3]);
```

Untested.